# Calculate the line integral: $\vec{F}(x,y)=(x^{2}+y^{2})i+(x^{2}-y^{2})j$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Calculate the line integral of,
$$\vec{F}(x,y)=(x^{2}+y^{2})i+(x^{2}-y^{2})j$$
along the curve described
a) by the equation: $y=1-|1-x|$ from $(0,0)$ at $(2,0)$

b) the closed curve described by the equations $y=1-|1-x|$ and $y=0$ in a counterclockwise direction

I need to expose the exercise

Comment: What about your attempts?

Comment: Hello, above all, I wanted to compare my answer, since the book tells me that the answer is 4/3 and I got 2/3, can you help me with that?

Comment: I already know what my error is ... I'm sorry, do not add the results ... You could explain how to do the second literal, I do not understand what you mean by "closed curve" or how to proceed ... please

Comment: Plot the functions $f(x)=1-|1-x|$ and $y=0$. The triangle that forms is the closed curve that the problem says.

Comment: The first literal understood it well ... but the second one, which has to do the integral line evaluation, $$\int_{0}^{1}(x^{2}+y^{2})dx+(x^{2}-y^{2})dy, $$ and if I use the parameterization for example, $x=t$ entonces $y=t$ supposing that $0\leq y\leq 1$  entonces $$\int_{0}^{1}2t^{2}dt$$ yes?

Comment: Wait a moment. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

(a) Parametrizing the given curve $\mathscr{C}: x=t, y=t$ $ 0\leq t \leq 1$
$$x=t,y=-t+2, 1 \leq t \leq 2$$

$\implies$
$\int_{\mathscr{C}}\vec{F}.d\vec{R}=\int_{0}^{1}2t^2dt +\int_{1}^{2} 2(2-t)^2 dt$

2. Use green's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

For **a)**
Firts, parametrize the curve. The next parametrization works:
\begin{equation}
\gamma(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
(x,x) & \text{if} & x\in[0,1]\\
(x-1)(2,0)+(2-x)(1,1) & \text{if} & x\in [1,2]
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
Then, split the integral in two parts $$\displaystyle\int_0^1 F(\gamma)\gamma ' + \displaystyle\int_1^2 F(\gamma)\gamma '$$Only substitute the values to finalize the exercise.

For **b)**
First, recall that if $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a field and $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ then the line integral of $F$ over the curve $\gamma$ is $\displaystyle\int_a^b F(\gamma)\cdot\gamma'$. You need to parametrize the triangle formed by the curves $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=1-|1-x|$. You can do it with a piecewise function like this: (note that this parametrization is counterclockwise).

\begin{equation}
\gamma(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
(x,0) & \text{if} & x\in[0,2]\\
(x-2)(1,1)+(3-x)(2,0) & \text{if} & x\in[2,3]\\
(x-3)(0,0)+(4-x)(1,1) & \text{if} & x\in [3,4]
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

Finally, the field in the exercise is $F(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)$. You can split the line integral in three parts: $$\displaystyle\int_0^2 F(\gamma)\gamma ' +\displaystyle\int_2^3 F(\gamma)\gamma ' +\displaystyle\int_3^4 F(\gamma)\gamma '$$ Can you finish from here? Only substitute the values again.

Comment: For a), use the same trick: split the parametrization in two parts: from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ and next from $(1,1)$ to $(2,0)$ and split the integral in two parts too.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much ... the first literal if you did it, the second I have problems ... but with your answer to the one below, you are more or less understanding ... thank you!

Comment: See my answer again. I added a partial solution to a).